# Data validation on a comma separated entry?

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that lists out Job Expenses like this:

```
COL A            COL B
CB100            $100
CB101            $200
CB100, CB101     $50
```

A few columns over, in COL D, is a running list of each JOB#:

```
COL D
CB101
CB102
CB103 etc.
```

I'm trying to use Data Validation to ensure any JOB# inputted into COL A already exists in COL D. Doesn't seem this can be done with List format of validation criteria. Any way to do it via custom formula?

Comment: You are entering more than just one job# into one cell? How do you expect to do that through data validation? If not through list format, how would you want to be informed about whether or not this # exists in column D? Can you elaborate, and also show your custom formula so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this custom Formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($1:$10)-1)*99+1,99)),D:D,0)))>=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1
```

[image]

Note the data validation is applied to the whole column A.  As you can see it was allowed to enter the first two but the last one was not as it is not in the list.

As is it will only test the first 10 number in a comma delimited field.

Comment: This worked great, with one caveat. Seems if the user enters " CB101" (begins with a space) as the JOB#, it registers as valid text. However, a VLOOKUP or SUMIF will skip over this entry due to the space. Any way to adjust so a space at beginning of job # becomes invalid as well?

Comment: No, because what if the user puts a space between the `,` and the next code?

Comment: And your SUMIF/VLOOKUP would require the use of wild cards due to the multiples anyway and so it will be found.